# Digital pen with realtime viewing

Tags: print-design, images, drawing, sketching

I've looked for this online forever but can't seem to find it.

Is there a digital pen that doesn't need special paper, uses easy to replace cartridges, and let's me see what I'm writing on a screen as I'm writing it.

I don't need anything wireless or fancy as I'm only going to be using it by a computer.

It's important that it's accurate as I write very small.

Comment: Took out the Adobe-Freehand tag as it sounds like the question is more about the input tool and not Freehand in particular.

Comment: Why would you need cartridges in a digital pen? It sounds like you're looking for a tablet.

Comment: @Nick *Real-time* printing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the best fit for what you are looking for is the [Intuos4 Inking Pen](http://www.wacom.com/en/Products/Intuos/Accessory/Intuos4%20Inking%20Pen.aspx).

It is an accessory for Wacom's [Intuos4 pressure sensitive tablet](http://www.wacom.com/en/Products/Intuos.aspx).

---

The Intuos4 Large has a writing area about the size of a sheet of paper (which you would place on top when using ink), and with 2048 levels of pressure sensitivity and a resolution of 5080 lines per inch you should have no trouble writing both small and accurately.